# Parsing inside a directory problem Python 2.7 vs. 3.2

Tags: encoding, io, python-3.x

I am trying to do some basic file parsing within a directory in Python 3. This code works perfectly in Python 2.7, but I can not figure out what the problem is in Python 3.2.

import sys, os, re

```
filelist = os.listdir('/Users/sbrown/Desktop/Test') 
os.chdir('/Users/sbrown/Desktop/Test') 
for file in filelist:
    infile = open(file, mode='r') 
    filestring = infile.read() 
    infile.close() 
    pattern = re.compile('exit') 
    filestring = pattern.sub('so long', filestring) 
    outfile = open(file, mode='w') 
    outfile.write(filestring)
    outfile.close 
exit
```

This is the error that is thrown back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bunsen/Desktop/parser.py", line 9, in <module>
      filestring = infile.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
      return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

The files I am parsing are all text files. I tried specifying the encoding in the method arguments to utf-8, but that didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

If I specify the encoding as utf-8, here is the error that is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sbrown/Desktop/parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    filestring = infile.read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not specifying an encoding when you open your files. You need to do that in Python 3, as in Python 3 a text mode file will return decoded Unicode strings.

Now you tried with UTF-8, and that didn't work, so obviously, that isn't the encoding used. Only you know what encoding it is, but I'm *guessing* it's cp1252, as 0x80 is that code page's character for €, so failing on 0x80 is common when you have European Windows users. :-)

To be compatible with Python 2.7 and 3.1 I recommend you use the io library to open files. That is the one used in Python 3 by default, and it's available in Python 2.6 and later as well:

```
import io
infile = io.open(filelist[0], mode='rt', encoding='cp1252')
```

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
filelist = os.listdir('/Users/sbrown/Desktop/Test') 
infile = open(filelist[0], mode='r') 
print(infile.encoding)
```

to be sure that you read your files in `utf-8`. If not, check if you haven't done something wicked with `codecs`. Also could you post the trace for your test with forced `utf-8`?

Comment: Thanks for the help Evpok. The default encoding is US-ASCII. I also added the error info when I force utf-8 encoding to my question. Curse you Python 3!

Comment: Wow, the same trace, how weird is that! And which encoding does print(infile.encoding) return?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
import codecs
infile = codecs.open(filelist[0], encoding='UTF-8')
infile.read()
```