# BeautifulSoup ascii error and csv

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, ascii

I have read all of the posts on the error, and still cannot figure out how to debug my specific issue.

From the command line, I am reading in a csv file.

```
adamg:NLP adamg$ python3 train_classifier.py samples.csv /Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/NLP/samples
```

If I open it as a byte file, like so:

```
training_pages_list_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(training_pages_list_file,'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    training_page_list.extend(reader)
```

I get the error:

```
  File "train_classifier.py", line 17, in <module>
    training_page_list.extend(reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

However, if I change it to read as a text file, or leave off the encoding, I get an error when the string is passed to a `BeautifulSoup` object:

```
training_pages_list_file = sys.argv[1]
html_page_dir = sys.argv[2]
with open(training_pages_list_file,'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    training_page_list.extend(reader)

for page,category in training_page_list:
    cp = CraigsPage(os.path.join(html_page_dir,page))
```

**CraigsPage.py**

```
class CraigsPage():
    def __init__(self, page_file):
        self.doc_name = page_file
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(open(page_file).read())
        self.title = self.soup.title.string
```

I get the error:

```
  File "train_classifier.py", line 22, in <module>
    cp = CraigsPage(os.path.join(html_page_dir,page))
  File "/Users/adamg/PycharmProjects/NLP-HW1/craiger.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.page = open(page_file).read()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6646: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think this may help as well:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065329/parsing-inside-a-directory-problem-python-2-7-vs-3-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, `csv` wants text, so don't give it bytes (a file opened as `'rb'`).  If the file's not ascii text you'll have to get it decoded:

```
with open(training_pages_list_file, encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
```

or whatever other encoding name you know is used in that CSV file.

If python 2, `import codecs` and similarly use `codecs.open` instead of the built-in `open` (which in py2 can't deal with encoding/decoding).  Or equivalently, `import io` and use `io.open`.

Similarly for the other `open` -- you need to inform it about the encoding of each page file.

If you have no idea about which file uses which encoding, then you're in trouble, as the best you can do is guess; a decent guesser is https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet , but, it **is** still just a guess .

Much like, say, a binary data file with no info about how its records are supposed to be laid out, an encoded text file with no info about the encoding is a truly terrible idea to have around, and you'll need some detective/archeological/forensic work, and quite a bit of luck.

Comment: My current code works for the first few files, then fails on the 4th or 5th. Will this try to read everything differently? And yes, python 3. I'll add that

Comment: Any particular reason to prefer `codecs.open` over `io.open` for 2.6+?

Comment: @Adam_G, not sure which is "your current code" -- the first snippet you give fails at once, so it must be one of the others, but of course since you don't tell us which, I can't guess which one.  The code I'm giving just assumes your csv file uses a single encoding.  Then to make `open(page_file).read()` work (the traceback you give cannot possibly be from the code snippet you show, so once again you're forcing us to guess blindly) similar approaches will be needed depending on each page file's encoding, if they're not all using the same one.

Comment: @JonClements, not really, either should be fine AFAIK.

Comment: @AlexMartelli - Is there a way to detect the coding, and adjust as needed?

Comment: Worth clarifying that the iterator error is irrelevant, the file should not be opened with 'rb', hence why this answer is about encoding only and addresses the second error mentioned.

Comment: @Adam_G, the best one can do is desperately try to **guess** -- encoded files lying around with no docs about the encoding, much like e.g binary files with no information about their records' layout, are a truly terrible architectural choice.  Maybe try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet , but remember, it can only **guess**.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will take a look at that. (This is my first experience do web  programming. Text files used to be so nice and orderly.)

Comment: @Ross, good idea, I did an edit of the A so it includes all the info in this string of comments, thanks.